# Stock Price vs Stock Return Autocorrelation

Tags: stock-market

There are a lot of paper that claim stocks follow a random walk and therefore not predictable. A basis for this statements often times a autocorrelation test of the returns. However, what if there is no autocorrelation in the returns time-series but there is autocorrelation in the price time-series? Wouldn't this make stock movemenst still predictable?